# for-loop with multiple columns

Tags: r, loops

I have a matrix with 10 columns and 1000 rows of data. I have a vector with 1000 rows of data. I want to subtract that vector from every column separately, using a loop. What is the best way to do this in R?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output. Read here [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)